# Safari Installation under Windows XP

Tags: safari, installation, windows-xp

I am trying to install Safari 5.0.5 under Windows XP SP2 which is installed under VirtualBox 4.0.4. However, when I clicked on the setup installer, nothing happens and no message of any kind. I also redownloaded the setup but the same thing happening again.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, what you are trying to do is run Safari inside of Windows XP SP2 inside of Virtual Box inside of OS X?

Comment: @bmbaeb: Safari inside of Windows XP SP2 inside of Virtual Box inside Fedora 14

Comment: Why do you do that and why do you need Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following course of action:

1) Check the event viewer (guest OS) in order to fully discard a problem with the Safari installer.

2) Increase memory size on your virtual machine.

3) Try to install another version of Safari.

4) Upgrade your VirtualBox.

5) Check the VirtualBox documentation in order to see if a tweak in the virtual machine should correct the problem.

If none of the above solves the problem then I would think in a compatibility issue among your host OS and VirtualBox.